# Seeking sources that support the view that the Rebbe (R. M. M. Schneerson) is alive

Tags: chabad, chassidic-rebbe, messianism

I know that within Chabad some claim that the Rebbe (Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson) is **alive *begouf gashmi*** (in a physical body).

Some say:

- That he is alive in **770 Eastern Parkway** (Chabad-Lubavitch world headquarters), as is [claimed here](https://www.hageula.com/geula_moshiach/study/23937.htm):

> אך הבסיס לכל העניין הוא בספר התניא, בפרק ב' ומ"ב יחד עם הערות הרבי שליט"א מלך המשיח שם,ונקודת הביאור הוא: מהותו של רבי, מסביר אדמו"ר הזקן, שהוא נמצא דווקא כאן למטה בגשמיות, בעולם הזה הגשמי. ולמרות שהוא לא נמצא בעולמות העליונים, אלא במקום נמוך כל כך יחד עם שאר בני ישראל, יחד עם זה הוא בטל ודבוק בתכלית לקב"ה, וממילא דווקא בגלל היותו מחבר שתי קצוות אלה - הוא יכול להיות 'ראש בני ישראל' ולחבר אותנו לקב"ה.

- That he is alive in the **Ohel** (his monumental tomb) on the basis of [Sotah 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.13a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> חוּשִׁים בְּרֵיהּ דְּדָן תַּמָּן הֲוָה, וְיַקִּירָן לֵיהּ אוּדְנֵיהּ. אֲמַר לְהוּ: מַאי הַאי? וְאָמְרוּ לֵיהּ: קָא מְעַכֵּב הַאי עַד דְּאָתֵי נַפְתָּלִי מֵאַרְעָא דְּמִצְרַיִם. אֲמַר לְהוּ: וְעַד דְּאָתֵי נַפְתָּלִי מֵאַרְעָא דְּמִצְרַיִם, יְהֵא אֲבִי אַבָּא מוּטָל בְּבִזָּיוֹן? שְׁקַל קוּלְפָא מַחְיֵיהּ אַרֵישֵׁיהּ, נָתְרָן עֵינֵיהּ וּנְפַלוּ אַכַּרְעָא דְיַעֲקֹב, פַּתְחִינְהוּ יַעֲקֹב לְעֵינֵיהּ וְאַחֵיךְ. וְהַיְינוּ דִּכְתִיב ״יִשְׂמַח צַדִּיק כִּי חָזָה נָקָם פְּעָמָיו יִרְחַץ בְּדַם הָרָשָׁע״.

I am looking for sources that indicate that every real tsadik (righteous person) is alive in his kever (grave).

I know that there are sichos (talks) of the Rebbe on Vayechi and Yaakov Avinu lo met (Jacob our father did not die Ta'anit 5b) but I cannot find the right one.

I also know there's a maamer (discourse) that was given by the Rebbe on Shemos but I forgot the year where he explains that without being in a gouf gashmi (physical body) nothing can continue...

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you

***Moshiach now!***

Comment: Please provide some source material for the claims you are making such as "lots of proof that the rebbe is alive beguf gashmi".

Comment: Secondly, it seems like there is a bit of confusion, considering, you don't need "proof" that i am alive beguf gashmi, the proof is that i am alive beguf GASHMI. Assuming you indeed have source material, wouldn't that be secondary to the most obvious proof - that there is indeed a guf gashmi at which you can point and say "hiney zeh bah"?

Comment: for example it's written in tanya igueros kodesh perek 25 I think 
that a tzadik after his death is more alive than when he was. in this world vekhoule..

Comment: Would that apply equally to the author of the tanya, the Alter Rebbe, is he too alive beguf gashmi?

Comment: well the rebbe already said on the friedriker rebbe shlita
so I think that all tsadikims are alive

Comment: I think you are mistaken, what you mean is that there were a couple instances in the years closely following the Rayatz histalkus that during a farbrengen the rebbe used the YIDDISH expression "zol gezunt zayin" which had been become habit to say about the rayatz, and when printed in HEBREW it used the phrase "shlita". in fact the rebbe NEVER used the phrase "Shlita" about the rayatz after his death. and considering the context, it was simply an old habit that the rebbe used during a farbrengen....consider how many times the rebbe approved and used the phrases denoted death for the rayatz....

Comment: https://youtu.be/bUxZ2IaaX8A?t=750

Comment: actually I don't say yechi and I am not realy meshi but I just wanted to have the date of those maamorim and sichos 
like I know those sichos exist

Comment: Please provide some more evidence based proof for what you are presuming is fact, this will better help users provide you with accurate answers and information.

Comment: When the Rayatz was rebbe, his son-in-law didn't do heseiba in his presence at the Seder. After the Rayatz was niftar, he did. Why? His presence "in spirit" vechuleih was not "begufo."

Comment: rabbi kaii I just finished to watch this video and I didn't talk about the fact that the rebbe is or is not moshiach I just talked about the fact that a tzadik never dies like yaacov avinou lo met and yaacov avinou have a haiim nitshit 
so I wanted to know sources from the rebbe that a tzadik is begouf gashmi in his kever

Comment: @L770 sounds like that Lubavitcher is saying that that idea is only connected to the moshichist belief system

Comment: the major part of lubavitcher in france are not meshichist (they are not propagating their belief of who is moshiach ) and are not talking about the rebbe is alive or not because they all think it
and it's not good for hafatsa mayonos

Comment: @TheTargum Do you require more proof than what is recounted by Rabbi Yochanan in the name of Rabbi Shimon Ben Yehotzadak concerning the burial of Yaacov Avinu? (See Sotah 13a) Yaacov was already embalmed and yet opened his eyes, saw that his grandson had killed Esav for obstructing his burial at the cave of Machpela and laughed. This tradition is also taught by Yonatan Ben Uziel. Sounds reliable wouldn’t you say?

Comment: @YaacovDeane Can you please include that in the question so that it contains some semblance of supporting citation.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the general teaching from the Rebbe on this, it is based on the meaning of Nasi (נשיא). That the Hebrew term Nasi is referring specifically to that individual in the generation who, like Moshe Rabbeinu in his generation, is equated with the entire nation of Israel. He is a “spark” of Yaacov Avinu. This is also why the Rebbe would not refer to the leader of the state of Israel as Nasi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150511/discussion-between-l770-and-yaacov-deane).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your (unsubstantiated) question, possibly the sicha you are referencing in Shemos is Shemos Chelek 26.

There, the Rebbe says that the leader of the generation (נשיא הדור) needs to be in a physical body.

Comment: thank you i thought it was in a maamer

Comment: there are three sichos in this chelek for shemos do you know what is the one i am looking for 
thank you so much

Comment: Not off hand. please also update your original question with supporting sources.

Comment: "Not off hand" what does it mean? sorry english is not my mother thongue
and I don't have the sources right now

Comment: i do not know which page or which sicha in shemos

Comment: Likkutei Sichos v. 26 p. 7 footnote 66
this is the proof in the sicha of shemos 
but I was not looking for a sicha in shemos but for a maamar in shemos

Comment: the rebbe say in a sicha yom simchas torah 5711 (obvisoulsy after 10 shevat 5710 the hiloula of the friedriker rebbe) at the end of the sicha 
"י. לאחרי ברכת המזון אמר כ"ק אדמו"ר שליט"א:
חורף טוב, בריא ושמח, ושנשמע רק בשורות טובות. שכל אחד
ואחד -- מכל הסוגים -- יצליח בענינו הוא: תלמידים ויושבי אוהל
יצליחו בענינם הם, ובעלי עסקים בענינם הם. והעיקר -- שהרבי
שליט"א** יוליכנו לקראת משיח צדקנו, לארץ ישראל, לגאולה האמיתית
והשלימה.
והעיקר -- שהרבי"
"שליט"א** יוליכנו לקראת משיח צדקנו
the *** are for the footnote 36
36) ע"ד הלשון הרבי שליט"א אודות
אדמו"ר מוהריי"צ (לאחרי ההסתלקות) -
..."

Comment: @L770 Just for clarity, the Rebbe did not use the phrase "shlita"in that farbrengen, he probably used "zol gezunt zayin" which was a very common phrase to say after mentioning the rayatz (or the rebbe). since it was still the year of Aveilus, and simchat torah is a time of much farbranging, it is not unreasonable to say this was slip of the tongue. it happens to everyone. consider how many times the rebbe did NOT says "zol gezunt zayin" after histalkus. this entire conversation is semantics and an unfortunate aspect of Chabad post gimmel tammuz.

Comment: hazve chalom to say this on the rebbe 
every word of the rebbe is kodesh and there is not an error on the rebbe's words
how is the phrase "zol gezunt zayin" so different from the expression shlita
I know that this conversation is not geshmak but I have to understand what is the situation right know 
beacause I was born after 3 tamouz

Comment: Even a Rebbe can have a slip of the after a few lchaims and discussing the very recent passing of a loved one, such was presumably the case.